# Migrating from .netcore 1 preview XXX to .net core 2.0

Tags: migration, .net-core

I am trying to migrate a .netCore (Classlib) project from version 1.0.0 Preview 2.1-3177 to .NetCore - 2.1.4. I have installed .NetCore SDK 2.1.4 with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.

I am getting a strange error when I try to build my migrated project. It says" .NetCore SDK doesn't support targetting .netStandard 2.0".

However if I create a solution & new class lib targetting .netStandard2.0, it works fine.
Has anyone faced similar issue? What am I missing here.

UPDATE: My actual solution contains other projects which are targetting .Net Framework 4.5. Not all projects are in .netCore.

Comment: Have you migrated the code base? If you haven't yet, I'd take a look through [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/)

Comment: Yes I have looked at this page & have migrated the code base. After migration, the dependencies are not resolved claiming the error mentioned above.

Comment: Have you got a `global.json` anywhere? This tells the .net core tooling which version of the SDK to use. It could be that there's a `global.json` somewhere above your code repo, which is telling the tooling to use an earlier version of the SDK

Comment: If you do `dotnet --version` in a terminal/command prompt which is opened in your code repo, what is the response you get?